# HTML5 track subtitles and property cue and ActiveCue is empty in IE (internet explorer)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, audio, html5-audio, subtitle

I try to add subtitles to audio track. All browsers is work fine, but not IE10 and less. 
This is my code:

```
<audio preload="none" class="js-audio">
  <source src="TRACK_SRC" type="audio/mp4">
  <track kind="captions" src="SUBTITLES_SRC.vtt" srclang="se" default />
</audio>
```

Then i try to get some cues from this track:

```
var trackIE = $('track')[0];
var textTrack = trackIE.track;
textTrack.mode = 'hidden';
var cues = textTrack.cues;
```

In IE I get empty object.
Please, help me with this problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem,  wonder if you found a solution?

Comment: I replace audio tag to video and vtt files to srt, than hide video block

Answer (score 0):

For IE you need to set up the MIME type otherwise it ignores VTT completely.

Add the following to a .htaccess file in the same directory as your HTML file:

```
AddType text/vtt .vtt
```

Comment: I use wordpress. My vtt file path is: site.ru\wp-content\themes\THEME\dir\audio\dir\   Where i must add my .htaccess file ?

Comment: I try to add this file and code in all directory, where i have me php files and vtt file. And it doesn;t work :(

Comment: Hmm normally you only need to add it to the root of the site in that case.